# Live Migration without shared storage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm-switch, libvirt, virsh

I am new to Ubuntu and virtualization and I have been working on live migration of KVM machines without a shared storage. I have followed all the steps as described [in the following link](https://sappyit.blogspot.ie/2015/01/kvm-live-migration-without-shared.html?showComment=1469117870316#c2757666291651771728) everything works fine till the last step where I get an error message as :

> error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-07-21T17:51:19.498699Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu14.04.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0: Image is not in qcow2 format

I don't understand, the image is already in qcow2 format but the output says otherwise, I have even tried converting the image to qcow2 but the error persists. I use the following command to convert the image on host

> sudo qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O qcow2 ubuntu14.04.qcow2 ubuntu14.04.qcow2

where ubuntu14.04 is my image name

Any workaround for this ?

And is there a way I can measure total migration time for the whole process ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your first step is to check whether your image file is in the specified format by:

```
qemu-img info /var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu14.04.qcow2
```

If the file is in the correct format, you should have:

```
image: /var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu14.04.qcow2
file format: qcow2
```

In case your file is not in correct format at backup node, you might need to create the system image with qemu-img create command:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o size=<your predefined size>
```

Then perform the file copy again.